# shell and perl in same file

Tags: shell, perl

Below code i written in shell script but it has some perl command

while i am executing below script manually from form terminal i am able to execute complete code

but while i am using crontab i am able to execute all the line except below code

```
mixvl.pl $f `ls $f | awk -F "-in." '{print $1}'`-out.talaw `ls $f | awk -F "-in." '{print $1}'`
```

---

```
 #!/bin/bash
 rsync -avz /dacx /storage/mp3/
 if [ $status0 -eq 0 ];then
    FILES=/storage/mp3/*
    for f in $FILES
    do
           mixvl.pl $f `ls $f | awk -F "-in." '{print $1}'`-out.talaw `ls $f | awk -F "-in." '{print $1}'`
           lame -q0 -b8 `ls $f | awk -F "-in." '{print $1}'`.wav `ls $f | awk -F "-in." '{print $1}'`.mp3
           rm -rf `ls $f | awk -F "-in." '{print $1}'`.wav
            rm -rf `ls $f | awk -F "-in." '{print $1}'`-out.talaw
            rm -rf $f
          fi
       fi
    done
 fi
```

can you please help me to execute both perl and shell in a file

Comment: if you do not mind; what is your objective of running this script?

Comment: Likely, `mixvl.pl` is not in `cron`'s  PATH variable which usually is `/bin:/usr/bin`.

Comment: we are using above script to convert voicelogs  to mp3 .

Comment: we are using above script to convert voicelogs  to mp3 .syntax  to convert raw to wav mixvl.pl file1.raw file2.raw file.wav

Comment: then how to set the perl path for cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems with your code:

- `status0` variable is never set: use `$?`
- you have a couple of `fi` keywords with no `if` statement
- [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- you call the same command pipeline several times. Call it once: that's what variables are for
- in fact, you don't need awk at all. Use the shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- cron has a different environment from your shell. Most likely `mixvl.pl` cannot be found in cron's minimal PATH. Specify the path explicitly.

Try this:

```bsh
rsync -avz /dacx /storage/mp3/
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    for f in /storage/mp3/*
    do
        fileroot="${f%-in.*}"
        /path/to/mixvl.pl "$f" "$fileroot"-out.talaw "$fileroot"
        lame -q0 -b8 "$fileroot".wav "$fileroot".mp3
        rm "$fileroot".wav "$fileroot"-out.talaw "$f"
    done
 fi
```